Why does the order of -prune and -path change the output of find?
This question is answered on another stackexchange (stackoverflow) but I couldn't find it because I searched for the answer here. I'm posting my question here so the answer is easier for the next person to find. I will mark it as a duplicate.
EDIT: Apparently you can't use another stackexchange link to close a question as a duplicate, so I answered my own question below.

I noticed these multiple similar questions, but I'm not understanding how those answers apply to my specific case. Here are the two commands I'm running:


find . -path '*/node_modules/*' -prune -o -name '*js' -print # prints files



find . -prune -path '*/node_modules/*' -o -name '*js' -print # prints no files



Based on this answer, I thought these are shorthand for:


find . '('                                               \
           '(' -path '*/node_modules/*' -a -prune ')' -o \
           '(' -name '*js' ')'                           \
       ')' -a -print



find . '('                                               \
           '(' -prune -a -path '*/node_modules/*' ')' -o \
           '(' -name '*js' ')'                           \
       ')' -a -print



I read the man page for -prune and it seems straightforward. Why do I only get results when I put the -path before the -prune?

Don't mind the downvotes, you did the right thing posting an answer to your question after you found it elsewhere. You could however make the answer "community wiki" as it's not really your own.

@StéphaneChazelas done

@StéphaneChazelas really? Are you saying simply copying content from another Stack just for the sake of some ill-defined benefit to searching is the right thing to do? I haven't ever heard of SE network sites having such a policy, and IIRC for beta sites this explicitly discouraged. I don't have access to exact timeline, but it doesn't look to me like OP posted a question, found an answer, and then copied the answer. Rather they had a question, found the answer, and then decided to repost it elsewhere, making a new question.

I think I'll flag this for moderator attention and let them decide if this is the sort of posts we want to encourage. Otherwise there are probably millions of posts on other SE sites that could be copied here, and plenty of bots running around to do such copying.

@muru As you've said, you'll have to take my word for it, but this was the timeline: searching for answers along the way, I wrote up my question w/o submitting. Shortly after, I found the link to the answer on stackoverflow. I edited the question with the note at the top. My intention was to close my own question as a duplicate, but I had to submit it in order to close it. When attempting to close, I got an error saying you can only use duplicates from the same stack exchange. Since I couldn't mark my own question as a dupe, I linked and copied the answer that helped me.

OTOH: I found this answer through sheer luck. I spent dozens of minutes doing my due diligence until I stumbled on a link to the answer. It was in a comment (and if I recall correctly, the comment was on an unaccepted answer of another U&L post, so I could have easily missed it). The title, How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?, would have seemed irrelevant compared to titles like Why does ... order of the parameters affect ... `find`? If someone posted this here before me, it would have saved me a lot of time.

Copying the same question would be against the rules since that would be cross-posting. However, asking a question and then copying the content of an SE answer with clear quote markup to indicate it's quoted and reference to the original is fine and actively encouraged. See the relevant meta post here: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1396/22222 cc @muru. (note that neither slm nor I were mods at that time).

@terdon alright, and I don't suppose you think there should be any limits on it as well, right? It should be fine if I started importing posts from SO/SU/AU etc. here? "Copying the same question would be against the rules since that would be cross-posting" => only if the same user did so.

@terdon no sarcasm, I'm serious. I did like to start doing so, maybe a post every day or so, and I'd like to point to a comment from a mod saying that it's OK if anybody else objected.

Mods don't get to decide policy, as you know, so a comment from a mod would be irrelevant. For what it's worth, I personally see no problem with that but that doesn't mean it's OK with everyone. As far as I'm concerned, bringing in useful content while attributing its source is a net positive, yes.

@terdon thanks, that's good enough for me

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh/1489405#1489405 by SO user @LaurenceGonsalves.

The thing I'd found confusing about -prune is that it's an action
(like -print), not a test (like -name). It alters the "to-do"
list, but always returns true.
The general pattern for using -prune is this:
find [path] [conditions to prune] -prune -o \
            [your usual conditions] [actions to perform]

You pretty much always want the -o (logical OR) immediately after
-prune, because that first part of the test (up to and including
-prune) will return false for the stuff you actually want (ie: the
stuff you don't want to prune out).
Here's an example:
find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' -print

This will find the "*.foo" files that aren't under ".snapshot"
directories. In this example, -name .snapshot makes up the
[conditions to prune], and -name '*.foo' -print is [your usual conditions] and [actions to perform].
Important notes:

If all you want to do is print the results you might be used to leaving out the -print action. You generally don't want to do that
when using -prune.
The default behavior of find is to "and" the entire expression with the -print action if there are no actions other than -prune
(ironically) at the end. That means that writing this:
 find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo'              # DON'T DO THIS

is equivalent to writing this:
 find . \( -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' \) -print # DON'T DO THIS

which means that it'll also print out the name of the directory you're pruning, which usually isn't what you want. Instead it's better
to explicitly specify the -print action if that's what you want:
 find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' -print       # DO THIS


If your "usual condition" happens to match files that also match your prune condition, those files will not be included in the
output. The way to fix this is to add a -type d predicate to your
prune condition.
For example, suppose we wanted to prune out any directory that started with .git (this is admittedly somewhat contrived -- normally
you only need to remove the thing named exactly .git), but other
than that wanted to see all files, including files like .gitignore.
You might try this:
find . -name '.git*' -prune -o -type f -print               # DON'T DO THIS

This would not include .gitignore in the output. Here's the fixed version:
find . -name '.git*' -type d -prune -o -type f -print       # DO THIS



Extra tip: if you're using the GNU version of find, the texinfo
page for find has a more detailed explanation than its manpage
(as is true for most GNU utilities).

